# How do I generate id's for my XML file without manually typing all one by one

Tags: android

is there any way to generate id's for my XML component in android without manually typing in just like the butter knife injection.
suppose I created a xml file with multiple  components

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Enter Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gotosignup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:text="Create a new Account"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>
```

now how do I generate id's for these automatically without manually typing one by one.

Comment: Android *IS* generating the id for you, e.g. ` android:id="@+id/Email"`.  Q: What am I missing?  Q: What more do you want?

Comment: I mean If I have 100  component (button ,editviews etc) in xml file, how I do generate  findviewbyid(R.id.xxx) for all the components automatically without manually typing it

Comment: @FoggyDay did you understand my question now, thanks for the help in advance

Comment: @stdusic your last comment is different than your initial question. 
You want automatic generation for id's in xml or for findViewById in your activity? 
In both cases, it's not recommended to blindly generate id's for views. There are some views that you won't need to have access to.